# What is a view model and how can I use it to replace findViewById with View Binding and

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a basic bluetooth app in android studio and I am having trouble with view binding. So far I have this in my MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
        ...
```

Later in the onCreate I have this line

```
val btnONOFF = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnONOFF) as Button
```

and I would like to replace the findViewById using viewbinding but I'm not sure what to replace that line with.

The android developers website says to use something like this
`binding.name.text = viewModel.name`
but I'm also not sure what a viewModel is.
Here is my ViewFragment.kt incase that is helpful

```
class ViewFragment : Fragment() {
private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): RelativeLayout {
    _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: View binding and view models are two totally separate things. You can replace your findViewById call with `val btnONOFF = binding.btnONOFF` (capitalization may vary, using snake_case_names for resource IDs is recommended)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tutorial of [viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQjw8uOWBhDXARIsAOxKJ2Fxm9vJM1LBgZ0yaU56XWDm0-Dd1t4gWT8p1KeDajB6dvFxs1l8OvAaAsoaEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#implement) from here.

**ViewFragment.kt**

```
class ViewFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val viewModel by viewModel<ActivityViewModel>()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): RelativeLayout {
        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        setupView()
        return binding.root
    }
    
    private fun setupView(){
        binding.text = viewModel.name
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

You can customise your **ActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class ActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val name = "Hello"
}
```

**Note:** by viewModel is [koin](https://insert-koin.io/) injection.